# What's the proper way for a script to get the first line of a commit message for a particular symbolic reference in Git?

Tags: git

I'm looking to get the first line of the commit message for the commit referred by a symbolic reference like `HEAD` or `master`.

This is needed within a script that has to function reliably regardless of environment or git configuration.

I know there's:

```
git log -1 --pretty=%s
```

But `git-log` is porcelain and IIRC it's not allowed to use porcelain in scripts. More specifically, I suspect its output can be modified by configurations such as `~/.gitconfig`, so it's not reliable across environments.

Comment: `git log` should not be used in scripts *unless* you specify the output format yourself exactly, just like you did. FYI the plumbing equivalent (but more difficult to use) of `git log` is *`git rev-list`*

Comment: @JakubNarębski thanks!  So `git log -1 --pretty=%B` is the right solution to my question, or should I look into `git rev-list`?

Comment: Yes, in my opinion.

Comment: I'd agree. To avoid the added newline terminator from the implicit `tformat:` use `--pretty=format:%B`  Or `git show -s --pretty=format:%B`, or `git log --no-walk --pretty=format:%B`.